# Connection String not working with EF in production?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I've got a console app that is using EF6 to a SQL 2012 and Oracle server. I believe the app is configured correctly for Oracle but the SQL portion is giving me an error:

```
An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.
```

We are using Windows Authentication. I can use SQL Mgmt Studio to connect to server and look at the tables, etc. I even confirmed the table is using the dbo schema. So my permissions should be good.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Here is a portion of my App.config file:

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=oracle_user;Password=oracle_user_password;Data Source=oracle" />
    <add name="Server_Connection1" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=servername1-scan.pdc.*****.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PSTAFF)));PASSWORD=******;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=*****API" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    <add name="Server_Connection2" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=servername2-scan.pdc.*****.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PSTAFF)));PASSWORD=******;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=**928275" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    <add name="LostTimeDbConnection" connectionString="data source=PRD2K8002\PRD2K8002;initial catalog=Losttime;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This is running in VS? Your context is pointing at correct connection string?

Comment: This is running as the console app in production. The actual connection string is different because of Test vs Prod info but the connection name is the same, I copied and pasted it.